# ¿Por qué un "Hola" al principio de una publicación se elimina automáticamente al editarla?

Tags: soporte, ediciones

Acabo de realizar una edición sobre la siguiente pregunta: [Firma digital de un PDF con C Sharp e itext](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52939/firma-dgital-de-un-pdf-con-c-sharp-e-itext) en cuanto a la ortografía. Originalmente la pregunta comenzaba con "Hola como les va?", y parte de mi edición fue modificar esa parte a "Hola, ¿cómo les va?". Sin embargo, cuando envío mi edición para que sea aprobada, la edición que veo comienza por "¿cómo les va?". Al final la edité para dejar "Cómo" con mayúscula.

Mi duda es: **¿Hay alguna funcionalidad en el sitio que automáticamente edite ciertos textos de las preguntas (en este caso un "Hola" al comienzo), o es simplemente un error?** Algo similar me pasó con otra edición que realicé hace un tiempo (aunque no recuerdo en qué pregunta).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ¿Hay alguna funcionalidad en el sitio que automáticamente edite ciertos textos de las preguntas (en este caso un "Hola" al comienzo), o es simplemente un error?

Sí, existe esta funcionalidad.

En [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/209901) dijo Jeff Atwood (fundador de Stack Overflow):

> We now automatically remove salutations from posts as they are entered.
>
> I got really tired of performing this edit over and over, so anything matching the form of …

es decir:

> A partir de ahora eliminaremos automáticamente los saludos de las publicaciones cuando sean introducidos.
>
> Estoy muy cansado de tener que editar esto una y otra vez, así que cualquier cosa que encaje con estos patrones...

... y sigue una lista con muchos encabezamientos saludísticos, incluyendo *Hola*.

Y esto es precisamente para potenciar lo que siempre se dice: eliminemos saludos y agradecimientos, pues solamente aportan ruido y quitan espacio efectivo para el contenido en sí. Por tanto, tu [edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/52939/1) es fantástica (gran trabajo) y -según mi opinión- para hacerla un poquito mejor podrías haber eliminado el *¿cómo les va? Bueno, les cuento mi problema:*

Lo que me sorprende es que ese contenido pasara el filtro y en la [versión inicial](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32062) apareciera ese *Hola como les va?*.

Comment: Entiendo. Gracias por la aclaración, y voy a considerar esto para mis próximas ediciones.

Comment: @RodrigoSalgadoAtala gracias a ti por tomarte el tiempo de hacer ediciones tan concienzudas, ¡son muy útiles!

Comment: @fedorqui excelente respuesta :) ahora me surge una duda, ¿cuáles son son aquellas palabras que entran en el filtro automático? De hecho, no estoy completamente que esté funcionando ya que en diferentes ocasiones de igual forma he editado para quitar palabras como *Hola...* o *Buenas...* o *Saludos* por mencionar algunos.

Comment: @Flxtr yo también me he quedado con la duda, pues la publicación inicial tenía esos valores. Puede que haya algún tipo de bug que hace que esto funcione al editar una publicación, pero no al publicarla por primera vez. En cuanto tenga reputación mayor de 2000 y vea respuestas eliminadas, haré alguna prueba por aquí. Ah, la lista de palabras está en la [página que enlacé](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/209901). En castellano solo veo _hola_. Nótese que esa respuesta es de 2011, por lo que algo puede haber cambiado desde entonces.