# Los saludos en castellano ya se eliminan automáticamente de los encabezados de las publicaciones

Tags: discusión, ediciones

Hasta hace no mucho tiempo (ayer, de hecho), uno podía encabezar sus publicaciones con un *Estimados*, *Queridos* o similares.

Saludar es bonito, pero también genera un ruido innecesario en las publicaciones que Stack Exchange decidió reducir hace años con [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/209901). Es decir, desde hace años, encabezados del tipo *Hi*, *Dear*, *Greetings* y demás se eliminan automáticamente de los encabezados de las publicaciones. [*Hola* ya estaba presente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1530/83), pero ninguna otra de las que utilizamos en nuestro idioma.

Hace un par de meses, por un [caso relacionado](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2760/1674), propusimos que los saludos en castellano también se eliminaran en [Let's make the automatic removal of salutations language specific!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305125/209901) y... ayer nuestro CM Juan M nos comunicó que [estos saludos se borrarán](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306776/209901) a partir de ahora:

> - Saludos
> - Hola
> - Queridos
> - Gracias
> - Estimados
> - Buen( o | a ) s
> - Que tal

Por tanto, seguramente a partir de ya notaréis que hay menos trabajo de *limpieza*, pues esto ya se produce automáticamente.

Comment: ¡Gracias Juan M!

Comment: ¡Estupendo!  Ahora los edits tendrán que ser más sustanciales heheh

Comment: mmmmmm.. Me engañaste, me mentiste (como decia una vieja cancion). mira [Aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137501/ayuda-centralizar-datos).. en realidad es una maldad, es otro tipo de saludo

Comment: @gbianchi _muy buen día_ no está en la lista :) A todo esto, estuve haciendo pruebas y la cadena debe tener como máximo 23 caracteres. Si no, ya no borra ([pedí info a un dev](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304996/should-the-word-hay-not-be-deleted-at-the-beginning-of-posts-especially-on-sp/305336#comment997472_305336)). Por tanto, la regex completa no la tenemos, solamente un aproximado.

Comment: @gbianchi vaya, que no sabías cómo traer a colación la canción :P

Comment: los pimpinela siempre suman :p

Comment: Hola! digo... genial!

Comment: @fedorqui ¿Confirmaste que sea con 23 caracteres? Creo que sería uno de los puntos más importantes de la regla, y para agregar en la publicación... Sería el motivo por el cual no se aplicaría en casi ninguna pregunta

Comment: @Mariano no me lo han confirmado, pero [las pruebas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3165/83) me hacen ver que son 21 caracteres como máximo hasta el primer signo de puntuación o salto de línea, teniendo en cuenta que sea la primera parte del texto.

Comment: @fedorqui viendo [tus pruebas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3165/127) me di cuenta de que es en la primera oración (al contrario de lo que había interpretado -toda la publicación)... Retiro lo dicho en "*no se aplicaría en casi ninguna pregunta*"... Gracias por probarlo!

Comment: @Mariano seguramente el regex podría ser bastante más agresivo y aventurarse a eliminar mucho más con una probabilidad de éxito muy grande.

Comment: @fedorqui con el riesgo de un mayor número de falsos positivos... La verdad es que no soy muy fanático de que hayan implementado esto. Las soluciones simplistas de este estilo vienen siempre con problemas asociados... Y una solución en serio,usando NLP, conociendo lo que SO estaría dispuesto a implementar, sé que está fuera de discusión

Comment: @Mariano no conozco NLP aparte del significado de las siglas. ¿Cómo podría ser una implementación de ese tipo?

Comment: @fedorqui con [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-language_processing) podrías analizar semánticamente el contenido de una publicación, buscando si hay un "saludo" dentro de la oración, y evaluando si eliminar ese saludo no altera el significado de la frase... Explicado muy sencillo, y muy lindo... pero también significa muchísimas horas de desarrollo y análisis de datos para alcanzar algo así... Tengo algo de experiencia con NLP, pero jamás me metí en semántica, por lo que no estoy al tanto de herramientas actuales o hasta dónde llegaron en ese campo.

Comment: @Mariano entiendo, gracias por la explicación :) Y claramente, dudo mucho que haya horas de desarrollo disponibles para este tema. ¡Ojalá algún día!

Comment: Hola, gracias, sun saludo.

Comment: Cuando esta en negrita no se borra, últimamente he visto varias publicaciones que empiezan con una frase de saludo en negrita

Comment: @blonfu oh, ¡tienes razón! https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3165/revisions