# ¿Por qué unos reportes a comentarios marcados como "no relevante" fueron rechazados?

Tags: discusión, comentarios, moderación, reportes

En Meta, hace un par de días comenté en la pregunta [Títulos de baja calidad en preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3574/83). No leí bien una parte y pensé que se estaba refiriendo al contenido de las publicaciones, por lo que comenté que de acuerdo con [Los saludos en castellano ya se eliminan automáticamente de los encabezados de las publicaciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3149/83), esto ya estaba implementado.

El autor de la pregunta, eyllanesc, me comentó con todo el sentido del mundo que no estaba funcionando. En los siguientes comentarios aclaramos la confusión, consistente en que yo me refería a una cosa y su pregunta a otra.

Terminado el debate, dije que pasaba a borrar mis comentarios para no dejar la publicación *sucia* con mi malentendido. Los borré al poco y marqué los otros como "no es necesario" ([ahora cambiado a "no relevante"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313436/209901)) para que los moderadores pudieran borrarlos en un par de clics.

Para mi sorpresa, casi tres días después, de los tres reportes dos siguen pendientes y otro fue rechazado. Creo que los tres moderadores han estado en Meta estos días.

¿Podrían los moderadores clarificar cuál es la forma de operar en estos casos? ¿Debería actuar de alguna otra forma? En Stack Overflow reporto con frecuencia en este tipo de situaciones y en apenas minutos los comentarios suelen estar eliminados.

La velocidad no me parece lo problemático, si bien me sorprende un poco y tal vez sea indicador de que se necesiten más moderadores. Lo que me gustaría clarificar especialmente es el rechazo del reporte, para así entender mejor si es un error o es que me estoy perdiendo algo :)

Comment: En cuanto al reporte rechazado desconozco el porqué. En cuanto a la tardanza en limpiar los comentarios, admito que los reportes en meta los miro menos ya que tambien son menos comunes. Los otros dos pendientes los he eliminado ya, teniendo en cuenta que forman parte de una conversacion pasada que ya no es relevante. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b gracias por tu comentario. Lo entendí como un "ahora viene el moderador que lo gestionó y se explica", pero parece que no es así. Una pena, me hubiera gustado saber más al respecto para poder reportar con más precisión.