# ¿Por qué un moderador borró mi comentario en el que preguntaba por una edición?

Tags: discusión, comentarios, moderación, moderadores

Estaba paseando por Meta cuando vi que un usuario moderador hizo [una edición](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3895/revisions) a [una pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3895/83) en la que modificaba una parte de la pregunta, pasando de usar una lista simple a utilizar un bloque de citación para contener esa lista. Me sorprendió el uso, pues la página de [Ayuda de edición de Markdown explica, en su sección "Citas en bloque simples"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes):

> Añade `>` delante de cualquier línea para crear una cita en bloque.

Y no menciona ningún uso más. Por tanto, yo siempre lo he entendido como un recurso exclusivo para citar cosas que se dijeron en otro lugar.

Bueno, como sorprendió, dije en un comentario algo del tipo:

> Perdona @X pero me sorprendió [esta edición](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3895/revisions), pues incluyes citación a una cosa que no es cita sino lista simple.

Lo siento tengo muy mala memoria para recordar textos exactos y no lo puedo citar textualmente... porque para mi sorpresa mi comentario fue borrado y se dejó todo igual. Ha pasado casi un día y nada ha cambiado: no me respondió, la publicación la dejó igual y mi comentario sigue borrado.

Podríamos debatir sobre si el uso de la citación es correcto o no, si lía o no. Pero lo que de verdad me preocupa es sobre todo:

- ¿Es aceptable que un usuario utilice su rango de moderador para eliminar comentarios de otro usuario en lugar de debatir normalmente a nivel usuario regular?

Por mi parte, creo que cuanto menos se debería responder (*—Oye pues yo lo hago así porque X. —Ah vale, interesante. —Pues borro comentarios, ¿vale?*, como toda la vida) o dejar que el tema lo resuelva otro moderador por un tema de básica incompatibilidad. La [Teoría de moderación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/83) da unas pautas interesantes para moderar un sitio y creo que aquí hay unas cuantas que deberían mejorarse:

- No comunicar decisiones.
- Mezclar la actividad como usuario con la actividad como moderador.

Sé que un comentario es poca cosa, pero es que en este caso particular venimos de unas cuantas decisiones previas que siguen sin explicación, como [¿Por qué unos reportes a comentarios marcados como "no relevante" fueron rechazados?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3593/83) y [lo comentado en su candidatura](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2478/2017-elecci%C3%B3n-de-moderador-cuestionario/2537#comment8929_2537).

Opino que Meta debe ser el lugar donde mejorar el sitio y la inmensa gratitud que tenemos a los moderadores no debe ser tampoco límite para que se nos expliquen las situaciones. Agradeceré pues explicaciones.

---

Añado: tras una semana, la única explicación ha sido [un comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3900/por-qu%C3%A9-un-moderador-borr%C3%B3-mi-comentario-en-el-que-preguntaba-por-una-edici%C3%B3n#comment15022_3900) con una falsedad: que el comentario era obsoleto, cuando no lo era porque la edición que suscitó mi comentario seguía vigente. Además, sin ir al fondo del asunto que planteo en esta pregunta.

Para más inri, hoy he constatado que se ha modificado [un comentario de otro usuario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3900/por-qu%C3%A9-un-moderador-borr%C3%B3-mi-comentario-en-el-que-preguntaba-por-una-edici%C3%B3n#comment15055_3901) sin su conocimiento ([aquí lo pregunto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3900/por-qu%C3%A9-un-moderador-borr%C3%B3-mi-comentario-en-el-que-preguntaba-por-una-edici%C3%B3n#comment15082_3901) y [aquí responde](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3900/por-qu%C3%A9-un-moderador-borr%C3%B3-mi-comentario-en-el-que-preguntaba-por-una-edici%C3%B3n#comment15084_3901)).

Esto es grave y no nos podemos permitir tener un moderador que modifica y elimina los comentarios de los otros a su antojo y que además se niega a dar explicaciones.

Comment: Espero que sea un error porque me parecería muy grave que un moderador borre un comentario donde se le pregunta algo.

Comment: ¿Has considerado la posibilidad de que fuera borrado por reportes de moderadores no diamantados? No recuerdo si existe un vista para usuarios con un nivel determinado de reputación para ver los comentarios borrados y en este caso mas relevante cómo fueron borrados.

Comment: @Rubén yo lo dudo. Pero vamos, entiendo que fedorqui no está acusando de nada, sino pidiendo una explicación. Si la explicación es esa, pues supongo que el asunto queda zanjado.

Comment: no queda en sede este informacion?

Comment: @fedorquis Sugerencia anotada, una disculpa por no responder, al realizar modificaciones algunos comentarios quedan como "ya no es necesario", te agradezco el entusiasmo que demuestras para el sitio. ¡Gracias por involucrarte con nosotros para mejorar esta comunidad!.

Comment: @gbianchi no, los comentarios borrados solo pueden verlos los moderadores (y los empleados).

Comment: @Elenasys mi comentario pudo quedar como "no es necesario" hace un rato, cuando modificaste otra vez la publicación ([revisión 6](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3895/revisions)). Cuando borraste mi comentario, y durante bastantes horas, ese comentario no era "no necesario" porque tales cambios no los habías hecho. Sigo pensando que es grave y agradecería un poco más de esfuerzo en la gestión y explicación de esta situación.

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo con @fedorqui. Aquí el problema no es la edición (a mi estéticamente me gusta mas probablemente la edición con la cita). La cuestión es eliminar un comentario sin ninguna razón objetiva (si la hay, no cuesta nada explicarlo). Si nadie reportó el comentario en cuestión, eliminarlo sin dar una explicación a mi también me parece algo no deseable.

Comment: @Elenasys El nick es fedorqui sin s al final. Cuando se refiere al autor de la pregunta no es necesario mencionarlo.

Comment: @ArtEze bien visto. Si se añade algo más de texto al final de un nick, la notificación no llega (acabo de hacer una prueba), pero en este caso sí me llegó como bien dices porque soy el OP. La verdad es que no es la primera vez, en algún caso me ha ping-ado con [fedroqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2478/2017-elección-de-moderador-cuestionario?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment9249_2537), otras no ha usado la @... resulta sorprendente cuanto menos.

Comment: Yo quiero añadir que he encontrado casos similares o de otro tipo como cierre de preguntas argumentando que la pregunta es muy amplia o basada en opiniones, pero lo que ocurre es un total desconocimiento del tema por parte de los que intentan cerrar la pregunta, y muestran bastante prepotencia en su rol de moderador.

Comment: A esta altura, no creo q ningún moderador responda. Claramente estan leyendo y claramente saben lo q pasa en esta pregunta, y me parece q asi como tienen el poder de editar o borrar comentarios (entre otros privilegios), tienen la **responsabilidad** de responder a la comunidad q les dio dichos privilegios.

Comment: @ArtEze gracias por la información Ezequiel.

Comment: @abrahamhs podrías compartir ejemplos los cuales consideras la pregunta fue cerrada incorrectamente por ser "muy amplia" o "basada en opiniones", supongo que fue creada en base a lo definido en [ask], sería importante agregaras ejemplos para analizar esto puntualmente, saludos.

Comment: Tengo el siguiente ejemplo. En este la pregunta es concreta y concisa y bien planteada. Sin embargo la pregunta estuvo cerca de ser cerrada, incluso tiene votos negativos y me parece falta de conocimiento del tema de quienes intentaron cerrarla. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/215476/dto-vs-vo-vs-bo-vs-ejb/215521#215521

Comment: @abrahamhs a veces cierro una mala pregunta yo solo para evitar problemas futuros con ella y  las respuestas. Una mala pregunta genera respuestas pobres y comentarios en respuestass. Si se cierra se puede controlar todo mejor. Recuerda que una pregunta cerrada puede ser reabierta. Siempre puedes preguntar en meta o directamente a los mods para que justifiquen una accion o para hablar de la reapertura de una pregunta. La prepotencia no es parte de ser mod ni deberia serlo y si no se nos comunica que nuestros actos demuestran tal actitud, dificilmente podremos cambiar y mejorar

Comment: @abrahamhs el ejemplo que pones, es una pregunta cerrada. ¿Te has equivocado al pegar el enlace? Mi opinion de dicha publicacion es que es de calidad pobre. Falta mucha investigación por su parte. Parece que tuvo una duda y que lo primero que hizo fue plantearla aqui cuando lo que de verdad hace a una pregunta buena, es el trabajo previo. Además, algo que la gente pasa por alto tambien es el formato. Es muy importante expresarse y desarrollar la pregunta con claridad. Sin un formato adecuado es dificil de leer una pregunta, incluso siendo breve. Un saludo

Comment: La pregunta se cerro después, si no no hubiera podido contestarla. Y yo creo que si hubo trabajo de investigación, porque a mi me paso lo mismo, yo busque esos conceptos y no encontraba información. Termine adquiriendo el conocimiento tomando cursos. Aseguras que "falta mucha investigación por su parte" pero eso no deja de ser una creencia, como la mía donde creo que si investigo.Y esto es a lo que me refiero, no se deben tomar acciones como borrado de comentarios o cierre de preguntas basados en creencias o falta de conocimiento del tema. Eso es lo que da la sensación de prepotencia.

Comment: @abrahamhs pero la pregunta no la cerro un moderador.. la cerraron 5 miembros de la comunidad. y si te parece que esta mal cerrada, se puede plantear en meta una pregunta al respecto, y exponer puntos de vista al respecto y tomar una decision. Yo no soy experto en esos temas.. pero escribir vto vs jbo (o lo que sea) y no poner siquiera lo que se entiende respecto de eso, para mi, demuestra que no se investigo lo suficiente. No alcanza con decir (por ejemplo) tengo un error, hay que mostrarlo. Es solo una cuestion de tomarse un poco de tiempo, como hace quien contesta

Comment: @abrahamhs el usuario busca una definicion real, sin buscarla en la documentacion. Menciona enfoques dados por distintos usuarios sin añadirlos para ayudar a orientar la respuesta. En ningun momento dice o desarrolla las siglas. No aclara la pregunta, por lo que la respuesta puede enfocarse de muchas maneras (eso seria cierre desmasiado amplia)  y lo que tu respondes bien puede encontrarse en internet investigando (no por quitarte merito a tí si no al OP por no buscar) . Un saludo

Comment: Es que es eso, no importa si es un moderador o no, toda la comunidad toma esas decisiones basando en creencias o sin conocimiento. En esta pregunta no se trata de un error. Se trata de conceptos de programación que no se entienden. Y estoy mas de acuerdo con lo que dice @lois6b. Pero también entiendo a la persona que pregunto, porque a mi me paso igual. Yo no pude encontrar esos conceptos en internet a pesar de buscarlos, hasta que tome cursos y ya tenia alguna idea de ellos.

Comment: @abrahamhs entonces si 5 personas (las actuales necesarias para cerrar una pregunta) no te parecen validas por desconocimiento ... quien puede cerrar ? quien tenga un minimo de reputacion en la etiqueta? o 20 personas ?  Ya cuesta cerrar preguntas (la cola está siempre a rebosar) .Y repito, al igual que se cierra , se abre. Por qué esa pregunta no tiene votos de reapertura? Por qué hay un porcentaje bajisimo de preguntas reabiertas?

Comment: @abrahamhs Una duda sobre esta frase:_toda la comunidad toma esas decisiones basando en creencias o sin conocimiento. _. Consideras que esta frase da sensación de prepotencia? Un saludo

Comment: El problema no es la cantidad de personas para hacer el cierre. El problema es que personas que no tienen conocimiento en el tema votan por el cierre. Y hay un porcentaje muy bajo porque es mas fácil preguntar de nuevo o ir a otro foro que esperar a que alguien te apoye a reabrir.
Pikoh considero que te pregunta es una trampa.

Comment: @abrahamhs no es una trampa, es bastante directa. Quien consideras tu que debe votar en los posts? Quien debe votar para cerrar? Quien decide que persona está capacitada para esto? Personalmente, yo no me atrevo a juzgar ni los conocimientos ni las intenciones de todos los usuarios que moderan el sitio. Tu si lo has hecho.

Comment: Por cierto, esta publicación se ha creado para plantear un problema con un moderador electo. Como te comentó @lois6b, meta está abierto a plantear cualquier problema, duda o discrepancia que cualquier usuario tenga con cualquier decision de la comunidad. Aqui, todos valemos lo mismo, y se puede conversar sobre cualquier tema y tratar de llegar a acuerdos que satisfagan a la mayoría (a todos obviamente,es imposible). Un saludo :)

Comment: Eso es, respondiera si o no ibas a rebatir y como no lo hice también lo haces. Considero que deben votar los que tienen conocimiento del tema y la mejor persona capacitada para esto eres tu mismo. Y no se trata de tomarlo personal y juzgar, se trata de mejorar el sitio.

Comment: @abrahamhs te aseguro que yo nunca tomo ningun comentario de aqui como algo personal. Solo trato de exponer mi opinión y rebatir lo que va en contra de ella. No tengo absolutamente nada en tu contra. Solo vi que acusabas de prepotencia, y a continuación expresaste que la comunidad toma las decisiones sin saber de que hablan. Como puedes saber tu que, por ejemplo, el que vota el cierre de una pregunta, no sabe del tema? Esta incapacidad creo que invalida tu conclusión. Yo tambien estoy aqui para mejorar el sitio, igual que todos imagino :)

Comment: @abrahamhs esta discusion, sobre quien debe votar, la tenemos a cada rato. Desgraciadamente, un usuario que empezo hace poco, y ya tiene privilegios para votar, por ahi no sabe que debe votar y que no. Sin embargo, no todas las preguntas se votan porque se conoce el tema. Hay pregutnas que se votan sin conocer el tema, porque con solo verlas uno se da cuenta que estan mal planteadas.

Comment: Yo no acuse de prepotencia, dije que "da la sensación". @gbianchi Me parece que has dado en el clavo. Creo que lo que comentas es el asunto, me parece que los moderadores deberían tener sus privilegios sobre la etiqueta o las dos etiquetas que mas han contestado. Y debido a lo que comentas también me parece que un usuario nuevo debería poder votar. Pero los votos de cierre deberían ser aparte, cuando se tengan mas privilegios. Eso haría que los que votan ya tengan mas conocimiento de como funciona el sitio.

Comment: para poder votar un cierre, necesitas 3000 puntos en el sitio.. algo que no se gana asi tan facilmente. y lo que vos queres, es cambiar como funciona algo que esta hace 10 años asi. Bienvenida las ideas, pero tene en cuenta que no es un solo sitio, es una red, y un cambio asi es para toda la red. Te invito a que lo comentes en Meta.SE si te parece.

Comment: Si se que es algo muy difícil de cambiar pero considero que por ejemplo los moderadores si podrían moderar sobre la etiqueta o las dos etiquetas que mas han contestado sin que el sitio funcione así.

Comment: Se han creado unos debates paralelos en esta pregunta que (en mi opinión) se están alargando demasiado para este sistema de comentarios y en cambio seguimos sin una explicación por parte de @Elenasys o una disculpa o lo que considere pero debería dar la cara y aclarar este tema.

Comment: Concuerdo completamente con @blonfu, se esta perdiendo el foco de la pregunta, que ya lleva varios dias sin respuesta

Answer (score 5):

Es cierto que a veces los moderadores no hacen el mejor uso de sus privilegios como moderador y se exceden. En este caso te recomendaría que hablaras directamente con el moderador para pedirle una explicación de por qué según su criterio esto tiene que estar formateado como una cita, y en caso de no llegar a un acuerdo, ponerte en contacto con el [equipo de StackOverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact) para solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Gracias Macaroni por tu respuesta. Contemplé hacerlo así, pero como se acumulan distintas situaciones creo que es mejor que la comunidad también conozca la situación, así como dar oportunidad al moderador a explicarse _en abierto_ por si hay algo que pueda explicar a toda la comunidad y nos ayude a colaborar con ellos de forma más eficiente.

Comment: Hola Macaroni, ¿puedes citar algún ejemplo que recuerdes de casos donde los moderadores nos hemos podido exceder?  Podemos no darnos cuenta de que hacemos algo mal, por eso esta publicación de @fedorqui no solo abre debate si no que señala lo que los usuarios consideran inapropiado. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Personalmente, prefiero no poner ejemplos reales que puedan resultar acusatorios. Mi consejo es, hablar primero con el moderador en cuestión y como última opción recurrir al equipo de SO.

Comment: No lo considero acusatorio. Y si no lo quieres poner de manera publica, puedes contactarnos privadamente como sugieres en tu respuesta. ¿Has contactado ya con nosotros? Igual otro moderador limpió el reporte y no lo vi...

Comment: @Macaroni yo creo meta es el lugar indicado para cualquier duda/queja/sugerencia que se pueda hacer a los moderadores (si exceptuamos el chat). Si piensas que algun moderador se ha excedido en algun caso, no hay nada mejor que exponerlo para que tanto el moderador como la comunidad pueda expresar su opinión. No se trata de acusar, si no de debatir :)

Comment: Releyendo tu respuesta y los comentarios que ha suscitado, creo que sí sería importante que dieras ejemplos de lo que mencionas. Al fin y al cabo, estamos en una pregunta en la que se habla de un caso concreto, así que seamos objetivos y precisos y démoslos, para no alimentar teorías conspiratorias.

Comment: @fedorqui **he visto que expones públicamente tus problemas con el moderador Elenasys**. A mí personalmente, no me gusta hacerlo de ese modo. Ya he contactado con los moderadores por mensaje privado y ya te he dicho lo que haría en mi caso. Y no, no es importante dar un ejemplo personal. Las teorías conspiratorias no las alimento yo ;)

Comment: @Macaroni cada cual expone sus motivos como cree más conveniente. De todos modos, una de las virtudes que tiene Stack Exchange y que me gusta defender es la transparencia: las cosas son en abierto, las decisiones se explican. En el sitio que modero siempre he preferido que este tipo de cosas se gestionen en abierto, para así explicar a la comunidad cómo gestionamos las cosas y que el debate pueda alimentarse de opiniones de terceros. En este caso particular, además, estoy hablando de una situación que se repite y por tanto creo importante escalar.

Comment: Exacto @fedorqui "cada cual expone sus motivos como cree más conveniente", estoy de acuerdo con eso. Un saludo.

Comment: Lamento no estar para nada de acuerdo contigo. Por un lado, quien ha alimentado "teorías conspiratorias" has sido tu (_Es cierto que a veces los moderadores no hacen el mejor uso de sus privilegios como moderador y se exceden_). @fedorqui utiliza el canal adecuado para tratar este tipo de temas, que es precisamente meta. Esto es una **comunidad**, y es en **comunidad** donde deben resolverse estos problemas. Eres muy libre de tratar un problema que te atañe en privado, pero en ese caso dejar la sospecha sobre los moderadores sin darles la oportunidad de explicarse no me parece adecuado :)

Comment: @Pikoh no he dado absolutamente ninguna pista sobre qué moderador podía ser, si alguien saca alguna conclusión de las palabras que he dicho, es que tiene una mente un poco rebuscada. Así que de lo de las conspiraciones no lo entiendo. Por otra parte yo no digo que él no deba exponer a la gente públicamente, simplemente digo que igual que él es libre de hacerlo yo también soy libre de no hacerlo, y con mi respuesta simplemente intentaba ayudarle a resolver los problemas, como tú dices, porque a su modo de hacer todavía no ha resuelto nada. Me parece increíble que digas que alimento teorías...

Comment: @Pikoh "es una comunidad donde deben resolverse los problemas". ¿Qué problemas habéis resuelto hasta ahora actuando de ese modo? ¿No decís que han de escalarse? Estoy de acuerdo, contactad con el equipo de SO. Sinceramente, de la manera que tratáis los problemas y acusando a la gente de conspirar, no creo que busquéis resolver nada, sino alimentar una discusión sin sentido. Estamos para ayudar a la gente, no para atacar. Sinceramente, acusar a alguien de conspirar me parece una falta de respeto muy grande.

Comment: Mi intención no era en ningún momento entrar en una discusión contigo. Contactar con el equipo de SO es un último recurso que yo trataría de evitar siempre, creo que es mejor hablar las cosas antes. Y no se donde has visto ninguna acusación de conspiración por cierto. Ha habido un problema puntual, y como siempre se ha hecho, se ha tratado en meta, el sitio adecuado. Parece sinceramente que te estás tomando esto como algo personal, así que por mi parte esta conversación termina aquí. Un saludo.

Comment: @Pikoh he visto una acusación de conspiración en tu comentario (cito textualmente): "Por un lado, quien ha alimentado "teorías conspiratorias" has sido tu". Claro que hay que evitarlo, por eso dije "en caso de no llegar a un acuerdo". Las cosas ya se han hablado (y mucho) así que como último recurso, mi consejo era este. Me lo tomo como algo personal porque me has faltado el respeto a mi persona y además has mentido, y ahí lo tienes en los comentarios.

Comment: Lamento mucho que pienses eso. Sigo sin ver donde crees que te he faltado al respeto, creo que has malinterpretado mi comentario, pero si lo sientes así te pido disculpas. Mi problema con tu respuesta es que acusas en genérico a los moderadores de abusar de su poder sin darles la oportunidad de defenderse. Eso es lo que yo he llamado "teoria conspiratoria", y por supuesto sigo sin estar de acuerdo contigo. Tampoco veo donde crees que he mentido. Pero como digo, ya veo que es una discusión sin sentido, asi que un saludo y hasta otra.

Comment: @Macaroni me ha sorprendido que [tu comentario de más arriba](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3900/por-qué-un-moderador-borró-mi-comentario-en-el-que-preguntaba-por-una-edición/3901#comment15055_3901) esté en negrita, pues cuando te contesté no lo estaba. ¿Lo editaste tú?

Comment: @fedorqui no, eso no lo edité yo... Igual deberías reconsiderar mi consejo. 

Ya has expuesto tus problemas y has hecho llegar esta información a la comunidad, pero si no llegas a una solución creo que no tiene sentido seguir insistiendo. Así no estás solucionando tu problema.

Comment: Macaroni: igual que @Pikoh, creo que esta discusión no tiene sentido. Lo que sí creo que debería preocuparte es que alguien edite tu comentario sin tu consentimiento (nota: editar comentarios de otros es un privilegio solo para moderadores).

Comment: @fedorqui Pikoh ha dicho, y cito TEXTUALMENTE: 

"Por un lado, quien ha alimentado "teorías conspiratorias" has sido tú".

Más tarde ha dicho:

"Y no se donde has visto ninguna acusación de conspiración por cierto."

Dime realmente si crees que eso es mentir o no. Si eres imparcial, me darás la razón. Creo que ahora estás acusando a alguien entre líneas de haber editado mi comentario y no estás siendo transparente, tal y como dices. Yo no hablé de ninguna situación en concreto, si alguien se siente aludido creo que es su problema, decir que conspiro contra alguien es ridículo.

Comment: Macaroni, dices _Creo que ahora estás acusando a alguien entre líneas de haber editado mi comentario y no estás siendo transparente, tal y como dices_ -> estoy siendo muy transparente: un moderador (no puedo saber cuál) ha editado un comentario tuyo sin tu consentimiento. No sé cómo de separadas tienes tú tus líneas, pero para mí esto no deja demasiado texto entre líneas.

Comment: A mi me alucina que mientras se piden explicaciones a un moderador que usando sus privilegios borra un comentario, otro moderador (o el mismo) edite un comentario de un usuario. No sé si es una broma o una provocación pero no me gusta nada

Comment: @fedorqui entonces no me vas a decir si Pikoh ha mentido o no. Sinceramente, entre moderadores y no moderadores habéis expirado mis ganas de seguir formando parte de SO... No digo que yo tenga razón y vosotros no, pero me he sentido atacada por una respuesta en la que sólo pretendía ayudar, ni conspirar ni nada parecido. Os preocupa mucho que un moderador ponga un texto en negrita y os da exactamente igual llamarme conspiradora. Gracias por el acoso y derribo. Un saludo, adéu.

Comment: We recently received your request to delete your Stack Overflow en español profile and it is currently scheduled for deletion.

Comment: Macaroni: lamento que lo sientas así. No soy quién para mediar en vuestro debate, más que nada pues está en un punto de no retorno. Me gustaría quedarme con dos cosas: que sugieres tratar las cosas de forma privada (como decías en tu respuesta) y que @Pikoh sugiere tratarlas en público. Enfadarnos por eso no creo que sea útil, del mismo modo que realizar análisis profundo de cada comentario no creo que sirva para nada más que para enconar los ánimos. Nótese además que fui yo quien puso la palabra "conspiratorio" en el debate, tal vez con mala puntería. Sería una pena irse de SOes por esto.

Comment: Personalmente, lamento que nos abandones. Tu opinión es tan válida como cualquiera, y yo solo exponía mi opinión frente a la tuya. Solo quiero aclarar que "alimentar teorias conspiratorias" no es lo mismo que "conspirar", así que creo que o yo no me he explicado bien, o lo has malinterpretado, y creo que te pedí disculpas por eso. Tu sin embargo me has acusado de mentiroso en varias ocasiones sin ningun pudor, pero yo no me lo he tomado tan a mal. En fin, lo dicho, siempre es triste perder un miembro de la comunidad, espero realmente que te lo replantees.

Comment: ¿Es posible saber qué moderador eliminó una publicación tuya? Por otra parte, estoy de acuerdo, los moderadores pueden cometer errores. Admito que cuando yo fui moderador cometí algunos. Siempre se intenta mejorar, no caer con la misma piedra otra vez.

Comment: @Macaroni Te he enviado una invitación, me gustaría pudiéramos platicar, las aportaciones de los usuarios son valiosas y he visto que tienes muy buenas aportaciones al sitio, nos gustaría continuaras contribuyendo con tu conocimiento al sitio.

Comment: Que gran problema gratuito se formó acá. Sinceramente no entiendo ciertas actitudes, pero realmente me deja atónito que un moderador haya llegado y editado el comentario de un usuario para dar un enfásis que el comentario no tenía. Por otro lado, y sin entrar en tomar partido, creo @Pikoh que el comentario "alimentar teorías conspirativas", si bien no significa "conspirar, claramente se refería a que lo que se está haciendo es negativo. Hay que tener más cuidado al momento de asignar motivos/razones a otro

Comment: @Lamak como ya he dicho anteriormente, pedí y pido disculpas por ese comentario, que no fue el mas afortunado probablemente. Pero si lo analizas, al usuario al que contestaba había dicho: _Es cierto que a veces los moderadores no hacen el mejor uso de sus privilegios como moderador y se exceden_. El no exponer casos concretos y que moderador había actuado asi, si podría considerarse como "alimentar teorias conspirativas", expresión que por cierto primero uso fedorqui, y posteriormente el usuario, antes de que yo lo usara.

Comment: @Lamak y dices _claramente se refería a que lo que se está haciendo es negativo_. Si, y lo sigo considerando. Considero que lanzar una acusación sobre los moderadores de que _a veces no hacen uso de sus privilegios como deben y se exceden_ sin poner ejemplos concretos, deja en un estado de indefensión a los mismos, ya que no pueden rebatir ni defenderse de una acusación que si es claramente negativa hacia ellos.Mi error fue usar una expresión que no fue afortunada, fruto de usar la misma que se estaba usando en los mensajes previos al mio.

Answer (score -10):

en este caso el objetivo era tratar de dar más énfasis a los puntos citados en la [lista](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#simple-lists) en la [pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3895/recopilemos-ejemplos-de-buenas-preguntas) de fredyfx, debido al comentario se realizo la reversión de dicha publicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eliminé el comentario citado por el usuario el cual cuestionaba el porque modifique la pregunta, específicamente el listado.

Bueno en realidad la razón se debe a que después de realizar la reversión sugerida, se considera como "no es necesario" ya que el formato de la lista en la pregunta se revirtió.

Hay que recordar que como usuarios y moderadores cada día invertimos tiempo, esfuerzo y mucha paciencia para mejorar el sitio, en ocasiones los miembros de la comunidad o en este caso los moderadores tenemos otras tareas que en ocasiones nos dificulta dar asistencia personal a cada usuario más aún cuando no es un reporte a moderador, aunque tratamos lo mejor posible de brindarla.

Seguiré la recomendación para seguir lo definido en los [lineamientos del Markdown](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) al realizar ediciones.

Comment: Sabes que no estás diciendo la verdad: yo te planteé mi duda más o menos cuando hiciste [la revisión 5](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3895/revisions) 30 ene. a las 14:42. A los pocos minutos mi comentario ya no estaba porque lo habías borrado. Revertiste el cambio el 31 ene. a las 14:32, casi un día después y tras muchas horas con esta pregunta presente (creada 31 ene. a las 9:35). Es decir, solo tuviste en cuenta mi comentario cuando viste que mucha gente se había dado cuenta de que lo habías borrado para que no se viera.

Comment: Tampoco respondes a por qué editaste [el comentario de otro usuario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3900/por-qué-un-moderador-borró-mi-comentario-en-el-que-preguntaba-por-una-edición#comment15055_3901) para intentar meter cizaña. Me parece una acción gravísima que debería estar fuera del alcance racional de cualquier moderador y a la que deberías dar explicación urgentísima.

Comment: Para terminar, la forma _Eliminé el comentario citado por el usuario_ para referirte a mi resulta cuanto menos peculiar. Por algún motivo debes pensar que tengo algo en contra tuya y no puedes ni mencionar mi nombre ([o lo escribes mal para que no me lleguen las notificaciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3900/p#comment15032_3900)). Al contrario, estoy muy agradecido a todos los que moderan dedicando ingente tiempo. Eso sí, por el bien de la comunidad debemos poder confiar en que usáis vuestras herramientas con rigor y en este caso no creo que tú lo hayas hecho. Por eso voto -1

Comment: Jorge, todos los que estamos aqui creo que entendemos y valoramos el esfuerzo que ponéis los 3 moderadores para contribuir al sitio, y os estamos muy agradecidos. Pero por un lado, es evidente que borraste el comentario de @fedorqui antes de revertir la edición, asi que tu explicación es muy poco convincente. Por otro lado, es en mi opinión aún mas grave editar el comentario de otro usuario para poner el énfasis en algo que te interesa, si fuiste tú creo que te equivocaste gravemente y debes explicarlo.

Comment: Me gustaría añadir que no creo que esto sea un ataque personal,y de verdad creo que no debes tomártelo como tal. Si me admites un consejo, yo te recomendaría que admitieras tu equivocación y pidieras disculpas y así se podría zanjar este tema tan desagradable que no ayuda a nadie :)

Comment: 1- "Macaroni, dices Creo que ahora estás acusando a alguien entre líneas de haber editado mi comentario y no estás siendo transparente, tal y como dices -> estoy siendo muy transparente: un moderador (no puedo saber cuál) ha editado un comentario tuyo sin tu consentimiento".
2- "Tampoco respondes a por qué editaste el comentario de otro usuario para intentar meter cizaña".

Aquí hay más de uno que miente y mete cizaña. Como dicen, se pilla antes a un mentiroso que a un cojo... Y mantengo mi postura de irme del sitio, vine aquí a que me ayudaran y a ayudar a los demás, no a esto.

Comment: @Pikoh creo que [ya pidió disculpas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3900/por-qu%c3%a9-un-moderador-borr%c3%b3-mi-comentario-en-el-que-preguntaba-por-una-edici%c3%b3n/3901?noredirect=1#comment15022_3900) Puede ser que Jorge no fuera completamente sincero, pero creo que vosotros tampoco habéis predicado con el ejemplo. Creo que si hay alguien que no quiere continuar con este desagradable tema es Jorge.

Comment: @Macaroni No entiendo el porqué de está discusión. Diste una respuesta a fedorqui que este agradeció. Un mod te contactó por la siguiente afirmación: "Es cierto que a veces los moderadores no hacen el mejor uso de sus privilegios como moderador y se exceden.", cosa en la que no te has querido meter y lo comprendo. Lo que no comprendo es la tirada para adelante en la defensa de elenasys cuando él mismo ha preferido no entrar. Y si bien se ha disculpado el motivo de la discusión es la razón del borrado del comentario que no ha satisfecho a fedorqui.

Comment: @Macaroni primero quiero seguir animándote a que no dejes el sitio por este tema, lo que puedas aportar al sitio es muy importante. Y vuelvo a disculparme si te ofendí en algo, tratar de explicar posturas solo con texto y tratando de sintetizarlo todo puede llevar a estos malentendidos.

Comment: @Macaroni En cuanto a la disculpa, ésta se refiere únicamente a no haber respondido antes. Pero sigue sin explicar porqué eliminó un comentario de un usuario, y por que modificó (si fué el, algo que no podemos saber) tu comentario. A ti parece que no te molesta, pero a mi me sentaría fatal que alguien abusara del poder de mod para modificar un comentario mio.