# Saludar o no saludar

Tags: discusión, convenciones-sociales

Quizás para algunos sea un tema irrelevante, pero siempre he tenido la duda de ¿Cómo ve la comunidad el hecho de saludar o no al inicio de una pregunta, respuesta o comentario?

Entiendo que culturalmente puede tener diferente aceptación para unos que para otros. En lo personal, fui educado para “saludar” siempre… un hola, buenos días, etc.

Casi siempre veo preguntas que van “directo al grano”, y no me molesta, ya me acostumbré… pero a veces me puede el “toc” e inicio una respuesta/pregunta con un “hola” (Que luego quito).

Supongo que muchos pensarán que un “saludo” no le aporta nada a la pregunta/respuesta y lo omiten.

Solo pongo este post, para conocer un poco sus opiniones. Entenderé si cierran esta pregunta al considerarla irrelevante.

Me animé a redactar esta pregunta, luego de leer: [¿Cómo dar las gracias a los usuarios que responden a mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1624/c%C3%B3mo-dar-las-gracias-a-los-usuarios-que-responden-a-mis-preguntas)

Comment: Relacionado: [Los saludos en castellano ya se eliminan automáticamente de los encabezados de las publicaciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3149/22721)

Comment: Yo estoy a favor del saludo escueto, pero hay poco lugar para discutir esos temas en SO y si escribes un saludo, se eliminará (o lo editarán y lo eliminarán). Si la razón para no escribir un saludo es no empañar la pregunta o facilitar la lectura, me pregunto qué empaña o en qué dificulta la lectura un "Hola". Algunos por lo visto lo consideran algo terriblemente tedioso de omitir.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No poner saludos, despedidas o firmas es lo esperado en las publicaciones del sitio. Tal y como se explica en el Centro de Ayuda en el artículo [¿Cuál es la conducta esperada de los usuarios?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior):

> **No uses firmas, taglines o saludos.**
>
> Cada aporte que hagas ya esta “firmado” con tu tarjeta de usuario en tu perfil. Esta tarjeta forma un enlace permanente a tu página de usuario. Si usas una firma adicional o un tagline, sera removida debido a que creará mas ruido en las preguntas y respuestas.
>
> Tu página de usuario te pertenece a ti - llénala de información sobre tus intereses, enlaces a cosas en las cuales has trabajado o cualquier otra cosa que te interese.

Como indicas, los saludos se pueden considerar ruido ya que no aportan a la pregunta. Personalmente, sé que puede parecer más impersonal al principio -especialmente para usuarios nuevos-, pero ayuda con la claridad y a centrarse en lo que importa: el problema expuesto en la pregunta.

Aparte, algunos de esos saludos no tienen sentido. Por ejemplo, muchos usuarios empiezan sus publicaciones con un "Buenos días" o "Buenas noches", sin tener en cuenta que éste es un sitio global y hay gente de múltiples franjas horarias a las que ese saludo no les aplica.

Comment: Me gustaría comentar que si bien es cierto que explayarse en el saludo genera ruido, un "Hola" y un "Gracias" rápidos no me parecen muy contaminantes de la pregunta y suponen un soplo de aire fresco a la gente que lee preguntas *todos los días*, por supuesto suponiendo que la pregunta siga los estándares de calidad que pedimos.

Comment: La deshumanización social en la calle y los hogares también llegó al online. Dicen que un **Hola** es ruído y no aporta nada, pero mucho peor son los post mal redactados y cuyas preguntas hay que analizarlas como si fueran un jeroglífico persa, lo cual, entre re-preguntas y más re-preguntas, para aclarar el post y el orígen de la pregunta, muchas veces el ruido es mayor que un simple hola y adiós...

Comment: @DavidDPG es por eso que normalmente no edito una pregunta para quitar esos saludos si es lo único que no está bien. Solamente los quito si estoy editando la pregunta por otros motivos. En algunos casos, y como indican en otro comentario, hay un sistema automático que los elimina sin interacción de los usuarios.

Comment: @DavidDPG contrario a lo que crees son ruido, especialmente para el bot de Google que se encarga de clasificar que tan relevante es el contenido para su buscador.

Comment: Buenas. Si un "hola" y un "gracias" son ruido, a mi me parece un ruido muy bello. Mal vamos como sociedad si perdemos hasta eso. Y si el bot de Google lo penaliza, habrá que recomendar DuckDuckGo... Ya dejamos por el camino suficientes valores éticos como fomentar la falta de educación.

Comment: Por otro lado, SO tiene, asumo, suficiente prestigio por sí mismo como sitio de consulta como para mirar de reojo los resultados de las búsquedas a ver si es el primer o tercer resultado. Lo de quitar los saludos de manera automática ya me parece hasta irónico, por no decir que raya la esquizofrenia. Saludos.

Comment: @GuardabosqueS Recordemos que esto es un sitio de Q&A y no una red social, se deben simplificar al máximo las preguntas y las respuestas para que sean claras ahorrandote el maximo de ruido, tampoco creo que tenga nada que ver el ser educado o no por no poner un saludo, otra cosa es si entras en el chat, pero en las preguntas y las respuestas ya está claro.

Comment: Para nada lo confundo con una red social, @Marc. Si fuese así quizás "ubiera scrito alg similar a sto, hola k tal", pero no es el caso. Sea de quien sea SO, la educación es un valor que no debemos perder, y no creo que genere tanto ruido otorgar un gracias a quien se molesta en resolver mis dudas... Claro que es la opinión de un recién llegado.

Comment: Otorgar la propiedad de SO a Q&A es un sarcasmo: todos sabemos que es una empresa muy reconocida (Question and Answers Company).

Comment: @GuardabosqueS la educación en estos sitios la demuestras haciendo preguntas/respuestas que de verdad aportan, con aceptar una respuesta que resolvió tu pregunta, analizando y votando, editando y corrigiendo. ¡Con esto das ejemplo y ayudas a la comunidad!

Comment: Siento disentir, @JYas. Lo que demuestras con todo eso es ser participativo, coherente con la política del sitio, y sí, otros muchos valores y virtudes. Pero la educación es otra cosa.

Comment: @GuardabosqueS La educación se demuestra de muchas maneras distintas, y no solo con saludar. El hecho de no saludar no me parece ni ser maleducado ni faltar a nadie, y es lo que indican las normas del sitio con *evitar el máximo de ruido*. Te vas de las ramas en tus comentarios, no se que quieres decir con *Otorgar la propiedad de SO a Q&A es un sarcasmo* ya que *Q&A* no pertenece a nadie, es lenguaje común. Por otra parte, tu argumento de *ubiera scrito alg similar a sto, hola k tal* me parece igual de inválido, ya que no necesariamente tienes que escribir así en cualquier red social.

Comment: Por supuesto que la educación es mucho más que un saludo, @Marc. En cuanto a las normas del sitio, simplemente muestro mi desacuerdo, por lo expuesto arriba (un gracias no es tanto ruido, creo yo). Pero asumo que las normas no las hago yo, y si quiero andar por aquí, también es ser bien educado respetar lo establecido. Lo de Q&A es una broma, ¿no es meta el sitio para hablar de todo? ¿También aquí está mal hacer un poco de ruido?

Answer (score -3):

En mi humilde opinión, creo que en este sitio web está empezando a cundir la deshumanización. Me explicaré:

El no saludar, aunque solo sea un "hola", es, a mi entender, una falta de respeto, semejante a no mandar un comentario de agradecimiento del que hizo la pregunta cuando se la responden con la respuesta acertada. Pero hay otro problema que yo no llego a entender. Vale que para responder algo que no sea solución, se ponga un comentario y no una respuesta. Pero, ¿por qué no se puede poner comentarios hasta que tienes un nivel muy avanzado? Esa medida genera que mucha gente tenga prohibido el ayudar o dar sus ideas, que serán buenas o malas, pero lo hace con buena intención (ya que no insulta, ni trata mal a nadie).

Es lógico que alguien que acaba de llegar aquí no pueda ponerse a escribir como loco, pero cuando ya sabes de que va esto, se debería poder ayudar un poco más. Por lo demás, dar las gracias a todos los que hacen posible este foro, porque lo hacen de maravilla, es el mejor foro de programación que hay en Internet.

Comment: "*El no saludar, aunque solo sea un "hola", es, a mi entender, una falta de respeto*" si tu respeto se gana o pierde con un simple saludo, creo que estás valorando muy poco tu respeto. Las formalidades no aportan información relevante a las preguntas/respuestas por lo que el consenso general es que son innecesarias. Si buscas un lado más humano y amable del sitio, te invito a [visitar el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) ¡te sorprenderá (gratamente) lo humanos y amables que son los participantes!

Comment: Uno de los motivos de no dejar comentar hasta tener 50 de rep es para evitar problemas de spam. Una pregunta/respuesta es facil de detectar en la pestaña de activas/recientes y el bot Comunidad se encarga de detectar publicaciones abusivas o spam sin problemas. Pero los comentarios nuevos son dificiles de detectar en todo el sitio globalmente.

Comment: Sin ánimos de polemizar, creo que la intención del sitio (a diferencia de otros *foros*), es mantener la neutralidad en el trato interpersonal. Si bien, se sugiere usar un idioma respetuoso, también se sugiere evitar los saludos (personales o no) y sobre todo evitar respuestas o comentarios de agradecimiento. El motivo es simple: es la filosofía del los sitios de StackExchange. Si eres miembro de alguno de los sitios de StackExchange, entonces estás de acuerdo con las políticas del mismo, y ésta en particular es una de ellas.