# ¿Por qué combaten los buenos modales en SO?

Tags: soporte, preguntas

Me ha ocurrido varias veces ya, que hago una pregunta y de antemano deseo agradecer a todos aquellos que van a dedicar su tiempo a darme una respuesta, y sin embargo, mi pregunta es editada para corregir ciertas imperfecciones, algo que veo muy bien, pero no sé por qué contemplan dentro de las imperfecciones el **Gracias** que me gusta poner siempre al final de la pregunta. Yo entiendo que comentarios con el simple objetivo de agradecer quizás entorpezca la información importante del sitio que es el conocimiento que compartimos, pero un simple 'Gracias' al final de la pregunta como muestra que somos personas civilizadas, no es nocivo para nadie. **¡¡¡Gracias!!!!**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu mismo lo dijiste: _quizás entorpezca la información importante del sitio que es el conocimiento que compartimos_. Es exactamente por eso, mientras menos ruido, mejor para los que quisieran responder tu pregunta.

Comment: Estaba a punto de borrar ¡¡¡Gracias!!! pero acá en Meta las reglas son un poco más laxas.

Comment: Porque esto no es un chat ni un foro, es una herramienta para ayudar a despejar dudas y esparcir el conocimiento

Comment: Hola, creo que hablo por todos al decir que el principal objetivo de la pagina es ayudar, cuando un usuario se toma la molestia de editar la pregunta de otro es con el fin de ayudar a dicho usuario a encontrar la respuesta que busca y que esta sea de utilidad para otros usuarios. No lo tomes como una forma de reproche a la cortesía, saludos.

Comment: Piensa en las preguntas y respuestas como  algo muy objetivo. hay un problema, hay soluciones. Luego en los comentarios entra lo *humano* y podemos agradecer, sugerir, orientar a los demás usuarios. Un saludo

Comment: @fedorqui No es un duplicado porque no se trata acerca de agradecimientos por sí mismos a una  respuesta recibida (se está colocando antes de recibir respuesta alguna) sino de una forma de cerrar un escrito, una despedida.

Comment: @Rub aquí dice _deseo agradecer a todos aquellos que van a dedicar su tiempo a darme una respuesta_. El posible destino duplicado dice _tengo la necesidad de agradecer a la gente que contestó a mi pregunta_. Luego para mí sí son duplicadas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En el **sitio principal** los enunciados que no aportan a la descripción del problema o su solución se consideran innecesarios e incluso se les llama "ruido". De hecho, algunas palabras se eliminan de forma automática.

Lo anterior es porque el **sitio principal** está centrado en el contenido sobre asuntos prácticos, no es un espacio para socializar.

---

Por cierto, en [¿Cuál es la conducta esperada de los usuarios?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) dice (apliqué algunas correcciones de acentos y letras faltantes)

> **No uses firmas, taglines, o saludos.**
>
> Cada aporte que hagas ya está “firmado” con tu tarjeta de usuario en tu perfil. Esta tarjeta forma un enlace permanente a tu página de usuario. Si usas una firma adicional o un tagline, sera removida a debido que creará mas ruido en las respuestas y preguntas.
>
> Tu página de usuario the pertenece a ti - llénala de información sobre tus intereses, enlaces a cosas en las cuales has trabajado o cualquier otra cosa que te interese.

Relacionado

- [¿Por qué un "Hola" al principio de una publicación se elimina automáticamente al editarla?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1530/65)
- [Los saludos en castellano ya se eliminan automáticamente de los encabezados de las publicaciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3149/65)

Answer (score 7):

Estamos muy acostumbrados a las normas tradicionales de la vida diaria (lo cual me parece perfecto en la vida real).

Sin embargo, SO tiene un sistema diferente para agradecer el tiempo de los usuarios que contestan nuestras preguntas y al mismo tiempo, no entorpece información importante en el sitio. Las maneras de agradecer son:

- **Marcando la respuesta como aceptada.** Si al autor de la pregunta le sirvió la respuesta y cree que es la mejor para su solución.
- **Votando a favor de la respuesta.** Si el autor o cualquier otro usuario cree que la respuesta es útil a la pregunta original.
- **Votando en contra de la respuesta.** Se leerá raro que votar en contra es una manera de agradecer pero ¡Lo es! Con esto le decimos al autor de la respuesta que agradecemos su aporte pero que su respuesta no tiene fundamentos, no está relacionada o creemos que podría mejorarla por X o Y motivo.

Y además todo lo que te comento Rubén.

Comment: Muy buena. Explicado en [¿Cómo dar las gracias a los usuarios que responden a mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1624/83)